# CSS Grid layout: full height column that spans auto-generated rows

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I would like to build a layout which will have an aside panel that would span the full height of all grid items including auto-generated rows. Since I don't know how many items will be present on the page I can't specify the exact number of columns and rows in the grid properties.

State 1: Grid has 5 items - sidebar column takes 2 rows in height

http://take.ms/Naw9M

State 1: Grid has 7 items - sidebar column takes 3 rows in height

http://take.ms/fmE6B

The goal is auto expand aside whenever new items are added to the grid.

I tried using

```
grid-column-start: 3;
grid-row: 1 / -1;
```

to move aside to the right and make it span all available rows but since I'm not defining grid rows my aside only spans 1 row instead of all auto-generated rows

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}

aside {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make it span all autogenerated rows?